# Reset capital letter in SMS

Tags: sms

I've noticed that my SMSes don't start anymore with a capital letter, the same happens after punctuation.

Maybe I've accidentally changed some settings? How to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings > Language and Keyboard > Samsung keypad > Auto-capitalization.

Comment: Auto Capitalization is turned on, but many apps do not do what they're supposed to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have just had same prob trying to change get auto capitals back in text. I have found when on text input screen by pressing the cog wheel symbol bottom right of screen and you can select various setting, one is for auto capitals. It drove me mad 'til I found it, reckon I must have hit it by accident sometime. Good Luck hope this regains a bit of sanity, cheers.